# 3D matrix doesn't "update" values - C

Tags: c, matrix, sqrt

I'm trying to optimizing a for loop which calculate 1/sqrt(x) where x is the value in a 3D matrix.

```
    for(int i=0;i<=DIM1/2;i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= DIM2/2; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k <= DIM3/2; k++)
                {
                    out[i][j][k] = isqrt(in[i][j][k], 1, 0.001);
                    out[DIM1-i-1][DIM2 - j-1][DIM3 - k-1] = isqrt(in[DIM1 - i-1][DIM2 - j-1][DIM3 - k-1], 1, 0.001);
                }
```

I tried to calculate the first element and the last one in the same loop in order to split in half the for cycles, i don't know if the line of reasoning is correct but anyway when i run the code the returned value of the second instruction is correct, but I can't see it in the matrix while debugging.
If I try to 
`printf("  %f \n", out[DIM1 - i - 1][DIM2 - j - 1][DIM3 - k - 1]);`
The value is correct, but not present in the matrix in debugging and at the end i try to print all the out array but there are zeroes.

Here is the function

```
float isqrt(float x, float y0, float epsilon) {
    float yKNext = 1.5 * y0 - 0.5 * x * y0 * y0 * y0; 
    while ((yKNext - y0) > epsilon) {
        y0 = yKNext;
        yKNext = 1.5 * y0 - 0.5 * x * y0 * y0 * y0;
    }
    return yKNext;
}
```

I tried to follow your advices:

```
float isqrt(float x, float y0, float epsilon) { 
   //x= x *0.5f;
    //float yKNext = y0 * (1.5f - x * y0 * y0);   
    double newx = 0.5 * x;
    double yK = y0;
    double yKNext = 1.5 - newx; //y0=1, i dont need to multiply
    while ((yKNext-yK) > 0.00221684015)
    {
        yK = yKNext;
        yKNext = yK * (1.5 - newx * yK * yK);
    }
    return yKNext;
}

void compute(float in[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3], float out[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3]) {
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    for ( i = 0; i < DIM1; i++)
        for ( j = 0; j < DIM2; j++)            
            for ( k = 0; k <  DIM3; k++)
            {
                out[i][j][k] = isqrt(in[i][j][k], 1, 0.00221684015);
                //printf("%f  %f\n", out[i][j][k], 1 / sqrt(in[i][j][k]));
            }

}
```

The `fabs` makes the code slower and, if I don't make a mistake,`yKNext` is always greater than `yK`.
I can't modify functions prototypes, this is one of the guideline of the excercise, so I can't delete unused arguments but using fixed values makes the code faster, and it's the only thing that the professor considers.

Comment: You have a 3-D array and are iterating half-way along each dimension. That means you are computing one-eighth of all the elements. Yet you only have two assignments in the loop, not eight, so the other six-eighths of the elements will remain unwritten.

Comment: ...the second assignment in the loop does not use the first calculation, so the only saving is in the loop iterations, which will be marginal, and offset by the more complicated array indexing.

Comment: Thanks! I'm stupid lol.
Do you have any advice to make the code run faster?

Comment: In addition to that omission, you would be duplicating elements at the midpoints. Without more code, it can't be said, but if you have a limited set of values to pass to `isqrt` perhaps you can have them precalculated from a lookup table. Also `isqrt` itself might be inefficient - you always pass the same values for argument 2 and 3. For speeding up code, you need to profile it to find where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Please get used to supplying further information by editing the question - especially code. It looks as though you have a much bigger bottleneck in this function, than from iterating array elements. One (aside) suggestion is to use `fabs` with the `epsilon` checking. You'll also get a small speed-up by not passing those fixed arguments 2 and 3, but that is still small compared with the general approach.

Comment: Another small gain that could be made is to halve `x` before the loop begins.